# Missing JSDoc @param "props.children" type. and Missing JSDoc @param "props.children" type. with React Native FunctionalComponents

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, jsdoc, tsdoc

I'm using JSDoc & TSDoc on a react native project.

Here is the file:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, FC } from 'react'
import useUserData, { UseUserDataType } from './useUserData'
import { AuthContext } from './FirebaseContextProvider'
import { AuthUser } from '../../common'

// Initial state

const initialUserDataContext = {
  userData: {},
} as UseUserDataType

// Create the context objects
export const UserDataContext = createContext<UseUserDataType>(initialUserDataContext)

/**
 * Context provider for user data from firebase
 *
 * @param props -
 * @param props.children - application parts that are dependent on user data.
 * @returns a context provider for user data
 */
const DataContextProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
  // UserData
  const userData = useUserData(user as AuthUser)

  return (
    <UserDataContext.Provider value={userData}>
          {children}
    </UserDataContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default DataContextProvider
```

I have two warnings:

On the second @param:

```
tsdoc-param-tag-with-invalid-name: The @param block should be followed by a valid parameter name: The identifier cannot non-word characterseslinttsdoc/syntax
```

On the begining of the JSDoc lines:

```
Missing JSDoc @param "props.children" type.eslintjsdoc/require-param-type
```

I'm not really getting how I shall document the props I guess. Any insights ?

Thanks

Edit:

If I add the types as @param {Type}, TSDoc complain because it is TypeScript:

```
tsdoc-param-tag-with-invalid-type: The @param block should not include a JSDoc-style '{type}'eslinttsdoc/syntax
```

For the time being I deleted the rules, waiting to see if there is a better configuration.

```
'jsdoc/require-returns-type': 'off',
'jsdoc/require-returns-type': 'off',
```

Comment: you are missing the type: `@param {Object} props`

Comment: Then I have: tsdoc-param-tag-with-invalid-type: The @param block should not include a JSDoc-style '{type}'eslinttsdoc/syntax

Comment: Anyway, thanks, I deleted the rules requesting the types. Maybe is it a conflict with TSDoc...

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little old but for those who run into similar issues.

Sheraff was right in the comment so I'd like to expand.

Let's first look at the error/s:

```
Missing JSDoc @param "props.children" type.
```

So that means you are missing the parameters type.

Then:

```
tsdoc-param-tag-with-invalid-name: The @param block should be followed by a valid parameter name: The identifier cannot non-word characterseslinttsdoc/syntax
```

This means this:

```
* @param props.children - application parts that are dependent on user data.
```

Should be this without text after the param name:

```
* @param {Object} children
```

Then finally this:

```
tsdoc-param-tag-with-invalid-type: The @param block should not include a JSDoc-style '{type}'eslinttsdoc/syntax
```

This means you have added a type - {type} - which is not a recognised type.
A valid type means String, Int, Object and this is NOT because you are using TS. It's JSDoc needs them signatured.

So to fix I believe the below would do it:

```
/**
 * Context provider for user data from firebase
 *
 * @param {Object} children
 * @returns a context provider for user data
 */
```